# Euler equation in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to prove that the Euler equation for a Riemannian 3-manifold $M$
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \nabla_{u} u = -  \operatorname{grad} p \qquad \text (1)
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\partial u^\flat}{\partial t} + \mathcal L_u u^\flat = \frac{1}{2} d(u^\flat(u)) - dp \qquad \text (2)
$$
where $u$ is a (velocity) vector field, $p$ is a function on $M$ (pressure term), $\mathcal L_u$ is the Lie derivative along $u$, and $\flat$ is the musical isomorphism from the tangent bundle to the cotangent bundle.

By applying $\flat$ to (1) and recalling that $\operatorname{grad} p = (dp)^\sharp$ one easily arrives to
$$
\frac{\partial u^\flat}{\partial t} + (\nabla_{u} u)^\flat = -  dp \qquad \text (3)
$$
which is close already! Now the only step remaining is to show that
\begin{equation}
(\nabla_{u} u)^\flat = \mathcal L_u u^\flat - \frac{1}{2} d(u^\flat(u)) \qquad (4)
\end{equation}

I have arrived to the following local expression for the LHS in terms of the metric $(g_{ij})$, a local frame $(\partial_i)$ and its coframe $(dx^i)$, thus considering $u=u^i \partial_i$:
$$
(\nabla_{u} u)^\flat = g_{lm} \left( u^j\partial_j(u^m) + u^i u^j \Gamma^m_{ij} \right) dx^l \qquad \text (5)
$$

My doubt is how can I arrive to the same expression for the RHS of (4). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you have a coordinate formula for the Lie derivative of a 1-form? Should be fairly straightforward from there.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I don't. And I don't consider anything else on u: $u=u^i\partial_i$

Comment: Well, what's your definition of $\mathcal L_u \theta$ when $\theta$ is a one-form? I could answer this question but it's only of use to you if it starts somewhere you're familiar with.

Comment: Sorry @AnthonyCarapetis I was a bit slept before and I didn't understand. I am working with the Cartan's formula: $\mathcal L_{X}\omega = \iota_X d \omega + d \iota_X \omega$, where $\iota_X(\omega) = \omega(X,\cdot)$ is the interior multiplication. With this, the RHS of (4) reads as $\iota_u d u^\flat + \frac{1}{2} d(u^\flat(u))$. I tried to express it as in (5) but I did not quite reached it, even when considering that $\Gamma_{cab} = \frac{1}{2}\, \left(\partial_{b}g_{ca} + \partial_{a}g_{cb} - \partial_{c}g_{ab}\right)$.